Variable that modifies data when new json comes in, and updates in views
I have json of the format:
{
  "id": 1,
  "comments": [
    {"id": 1, "message": "Hello"},
    {"id": 2, "message": "There"},
    {"id": 3, "message": "World"}
  ]
}

And here are the models I have for this json, Post and Comment:
struct Post: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let comments: [Comment]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case comments = "comments"
    }
}

struct Comment: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let message: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case message = "message"
    }
}

In SwiftUI, I use EnvironmentObject to make sure that the view updates when the data changes, which is working as expected.
However, I'd like to create a new variable in the Post model which will hold all of the Comment ids in an array, i.e. in the example above the output would be:
var commentIds: [Int] = [1, 2, 3]

From what I've read, computed properties do not automatically update in SwiftUI when the data is updated, so I can't use that.
So how would I create this custom variable that would update each time the Post data updates, and would also update in my views?

You write the view updates when the data changes, which is working as expected, so what is the purpose of commentIds? By the way you can delete CodingKeys if the keys match exactly the struct member names.

I have not implemented the logic behind commentIds yet. I want to use commentIds in my views, but I am unsure of how to create the variable or make sure that commentIds updates in my views whenever the Post data updates.

Use a real computed property (commentIds is not) var commentIds: [Int]  { post.comments.map(\.id) }

My understanding was that when the Post data changes, computed properties will not be updated in the UI?

Why? The new data updates the UI already.

I hope I understood what you're trying to do. According to the 3rd comment heres your
UI updating computed var valueBinding(get: { post.comments.map(\.id) }, set: { self.commentIds = $0 })

In iOS 17 you can use the new Observation framework. Here is an example based on your question.
import Observation and then just wrap your model with @Observable, doesn't work with structs you would need to use a class.
import Observation

@Observable
class Post: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var commentsID: [String] = [] // <--- Don't think you should use Int as IDs
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    static let dummyPost = Post(name: "Post 1")
    
    func fetchCommentsID() async -> [String] {
        var fetchedComments: [String] = []
        
        for _ in 0..<3 { // <--- Create some fake comments to add
            let newComment = Comment()
            fetchedComments.append(newComment.id)
        }
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2)) // <--- Perform a fake task
        
        return fetchedComments
    }
}

Now here is an example how you would be able to use it in a view.
struct PostDetailView: View {
    var post: Post = .dummyPost // <--- For example purpose
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(post.name)
            if post.commentsID.isEmpty {
                Button("fetch comments") {
                    Task { // <--- Need task since fetching comments is async
                        let commentsID = await post.fetchCommentsID()
                        post.commentsID += commentsID
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(post.commentsID, id: \.self) { commentID in
                        Text(commentID)
                    }
                    Button("fetch more comments") {
                        Task { // <--- fetch more comments
                            let commentsID = await post.fetchCommentsID()
                            post.commentsID += commentsID
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

Hope this helps. Happy Coding!!!
